# How to use asynchronous json2xlsx

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am using json2xlsx lib to convert a JSON to xlsx and then export xlsx with lib fs, however when JSON contains a lot of data the application to / "hangs" briefly until the conversion is performed. I guess I just can not use async await. Someone suggests a lib that makes it possible to convert JSON to xlsx asynchronously. Or some other solution.

```
const convertToXlsx = async (data, pathOut, nameOutput = 'output') => {

    let xls = json2xls(data)

    await fs.writeFile(`${pathOut}/${nameOutput}.xlsx`, xls, 'binary')


}
```

Comment: You are doing it right but the library you are using doesn't do it multi-threaded. After all node.js is not very good for these kind of tasks.

Comment: Show a loading spinner (e.g. an animated GIF) and hide it afterwards, at least then, UI wise, it will appear that it is doing something :-) Then you don't have to worry about trying to make it asynchronous.

Comment: @HAL9256 I'm using a GIF, it was exactly because of the spinner I noticed the locking, because the spinner hangs at the moment the JSON to Xlsx is being converted.

Comment: Maybe try [spin.js](http://spin.js.org) instead of a GIF? The CSS solution may work better than a GIF.

Comment: Not, the problem is not with the spinner, it's really time that the JSON to XLSX conversion is happening on the line: ``let xls = json2xls(data)`` the entire application hangs until it finishes converting.